# Displaying of pdf file on datagridview with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

The DataGridView won't show the PDF file from MySQL, it has red x mark on the table where the pdf. I want the file name displayed on the DataGridView. I really need help. Thanks alot. I'm using VB.Net and Workbench.

```vb
Private Sub Admin_Handouts_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=; userid=; password=; database=cai"
        MysqlConn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT Code FROM cai.subjects"
        command = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter
        dt = New DataTable
        da.SelectCommand = command
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgvfiles.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually have the file name stored in that `Code` column or is it actually the binary contents of the file?  My guess is that it's the latter, in which case it will be being interpreted as image data by the grid.  In that case, it obviously can't be used the create an `Image` so you see the error image instead.  If you want the file name displayed in the grid then you need to actually retrieve the file name from the database.

Comment: I have the file stored in my database, How can i retrieve it? Thanks.

Comment: It's like you didn't even read my comment. The contents of the file and the name of the file are two different things. Which one do you want? You say that you want to display the name of the file but you are apparently retrieving the contents of the file. If you want the name of the file then store the name of the file and then retrieve the name of the file. The name won't appear by magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the iTextSharp library you can read the document properties from the PDF when you load it as an object.

I don't know if the file would retain the filename property when you add it to the table, though.

https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet